# Should you capitalize fantasy creatures?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, capitalization

I am currently writing a novel with a mix of sci-fi and fantasy setting.
So my question is that, I have one creature that is a cosmic beast with a species name "crossiax." Should I capitalize it as "Crossiax" or just left it as "crossiax"? Since it's a species name, I read that I must keep it lowercase.
And one more, I named a sub-species of slime as "Pyro Slime," should I capitalize it? It's the same as when a wolf have a horn and have their own species name as "Lone Horn Wolf."
I read a few novels (light novels mostly) and find out that they are rather inconsistent. Sometimes capitalized, sometimes not. Like when a dragon was a rare subspecies of its kind and is a "Red Dragon" or something along that line.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is "a special species"? Surely Gold Dragon is the name or title of the creature. That's why it is capitalized.

Comment: @Weather Vane I mean, a rare subspecies of its kind. Hmm, gonna change that part a bit then.

Comment: You've changed the name, so you are making up examples. Can you quote the usage?

Comment: We don't capitalize the names of species, except if we're using the Latin genus-species nomenclature (like *Tyranosaurus rex*). If you want to do it for your fantasy novel, you're the author, but why do you want to do this?  Are you aiming your novel at D&D players, who do do this?

Comment: How do you capitalize a creature? You can only capitalize names of creatures...In a fictional setting, you can do whatever you want.

Comment: @Peter Shor I see... so species shouldn't be capitalized, right? But what about sub-species like "Pyro Slime" and "Lone Horn Wolf" and the like? I see that a lot of novel capitalized sub-species, but why?

Comment: This is a style question more appropriate for a fiction forum.

Comment: Tolkien capitalized the names of his races: Man, Elf, Dwarf, Orc.  Can there be a better authority than that?

Comment: Why? These authors may be D&D players, and have picked up this bad (my opinion) habit from the game.

Comment: @Peter Shore Following GEdgar's comment I suspect that the developers of D&D were heavily influenced by Tolkein anyway. When the fantasy adventure games first started to appear, even as board games, I thought that they were, to some extent, influenced by The Lord of The Rings and related books.